# How to compare a text in an HTML element with a value in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, increment

This is my first JavaScript code - it's a quiz app.
I'm trying to calculate the number of correct answers a user scores by comparing the user's selected text witht the correct answer text and everytime they do, the userScore variable should increment. In this however, it's returning the value that's initally defined, a.k.a 0

I have the entire code mentioned below

!!SOLVED!!
Focus on the selectAnswer() function -the answer lies there

```
//select all the elements of the page

const startCard = document.getElementById('on-start');
const quizCard = document.getElementById('after-start');
const questionNumberElement = document.querySelector('.question-number');
// const timerBox = document.querySelector('.timer');
const questionElement = document.querySelector('.question');
const answersElement = document.getElementById('answers');
const answerElement = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
const quitButton = document.querySelector('.quit');
const endCard = document.getElementById('the-end');
const scoreElement = document.querySelector('.score');
const messageElement = document.querySelector('.message');
const tryAgain = document.querySelector('.try-again');




let que_count = 0;
let userScore = 0;
// let timeValue = 10;

startCard.onclick = () => {
    //intro hides and quiz card shows
    startCard.classList.add('hide');
    quizCard.classList.remove('hide');
    //show all questions and answers
    // startTimer(10);
    showQuestion(0);
    //timer re-starts
}

// function startTimer(time) {
//     counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
//     function timer() {
//         timerBox.textContent = time;
//         time--;
//         if (time < 9) {
//             let addZero = timerBox.textContent;
//             timerBox.textContent = '0' + addZero;
//         }
//         if (time < 0) {
//             clearInterval(counter);
//             // nextQuestion();
//         }
//     }
// }

tryAgain.onclick = () => {
    window.location.reload();
}

quitButton.onclick = () => {
    window.location.reload();
}

function showQuestion(index) {
    //question number changes
    let queNumber = 'Question ' + questions[index].numb;
    questionNumberElement.innerHTML = queNumber;

    //question changes
    let que = questions[index].question;
    questionElement.innerHTML = que;

    //answers change
    questions[index].answers.forEach(answer => {
        const button = document.createElement('button')
        button.innerText = answer.text
        button.classList.add('answer')
        //when answer is selected
        if (answer.correct) {
            button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
        }
        button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
        // index++;
        answersElement.appendChild(button)
    })
}

function selectAnswer(answer) {
    let userAns = answer.target.innerText;
    let correctAns = questions[que_count].rightAnswer;
    if (userAns == correctAns) {
        userScore++;
    }
    resetState();
    if (que_count < questions.length - 1) {
        nextQuestion();
    }
    else {
        showResult();
    }
}

function showResult() {
    quizCard.classList.add('hide');
    startCard.classList.add('hide');
    endCard.classList.remove('hide');

    let score = ((userScore / questions.length) * 100);
    let score_message = 'You scored a ' + score + '%';
    scoreElement.innerText = score_message;

    if (score <= 40) {
        let msg = messages[5];
        messageElement.innerText = msg;
    }
    else if (score <= 50) {
        let msg = messages[4];
        messageElement.innerText = msg;
    }
    else if (score <= 60) {
        let msg = messages[3];
        messageElement.innerText = msg;
    }
    else if (score < 70) {
        let msg = messages[2];
        messageElement.innerText = msg;
    }
    else if (score < 80) {
        let msg = messages[1];
        messageElement.innerText = msg;
    }
    else {
        let msg = messages[0];
        messageElement.innerText = msg;
    }
}

function nextQuestion() {
    que_count++;
    showQuestion(que_count);
    // startTimer(timeValue);
}

function resetState() {
    // clearStatusClass(document.body)
    while (answersElement.firstChild) {
        answersElement.removeChild(answersElement.firstChild)
    }
}

const questions = [
    {
        numb: 1,
        question: 'When did Will Byers go missing',
        rightAnswer: 'November 6th, 1983',
        answers: [
            { text: 'November 6th, 1983' },
            { text: 'October 6th, 1983' },
            { text: 'November 9th, 1989' },
            { text: 'September 6th, 1983' }
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 2,
        rightAnswer: 'Bob Newby',
        question: 'Who founded Hawkins Middle School AV Club',
        answers: [
            { text: 'Mr. Clarke' },
            { text: 'Bob Newby' },
            { text: 'Joyce Byers' },
            { text: 'Dustin Henderson' }
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 3,
        rightAnswer: 'Cherry',
        question: 'What flavour slurpee does Alexei ask Hopper?',
        answers: [
            { text: 'Strawberry' },
            { text: 'Blueberry' },
            { text: 'Cherry' },
            { text: 'Mango' }
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 4,
        rightAnswer: 'Mike Wheeler',
        question: '\'If anyone asks where I am, I\'ve left the country\'',
        answers: [
            { text: 'Erica Sinclair' },
            { text: 'Lucas Sinclair' },
            { text: 'Mike Wheeler' },
            { text: 'Jim Hopper' }
        ]
    }
]

const messages = [
    'Excellent job! You got way too much free time buddy',
    'Great score! You must love Steve a lot huh',
    'Good score, my man. I\'m sure we\'re both looking forward for s4',
    'You should rewatch!!',
    'You should rewatch!',
    'Okay... Get outta here'
]
    // { num: 1, message: 'Excellent' }, //90+
    // { num: 2, message: 'Great' }, //80+
    // { num: 3, message: 'Good' },
    // { num: 4, message: 'Alright' },
    // { num: 5, message: 'Poor' },
    // { num: 6, message: 'Very Poor' }
```

This is the HTML portion of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="quiz-card">
        <div id="on-start">
            <div class="intro">How well do you know Stranger Things?</div>
            <button class="start" id="start-btn">Start</button>
        </div>

        <div id="after-start" class='hide'>
            <div class="question-timer" id='question'>
                <div class="question-number"></div>
                <div class="timer">0:00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="question">Which actor plays Steve Harrington?</div>
            <div class="answers" id="answers">
                <!-- <button class="answer">hi</button>
                <button class="answer">there</button>
                <button class="answer">sweety</button>
                <button class="answer">hehe</button> -->
            </div>
            <button class="quit">Quit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="the-end" class="hide">
            <h5 class="result">
                <div class="score"></div>
                <div class="message"></div>
            </h5>
            <button class="try-again">Try again</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script-2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well done on writing your first JavaScript!

The first thing I noticed is that in your `questions` array, in question 2, you've got a syntax issue. In the question, you're using an apostrophe in the word "What's", and that's telling JavaScript it's the end of the string. You'll want to either escape that with a `\` before it, or change your quotation marks around the string to double quotes `"`.

I don't know if that'll fix the issue, but it's the first step.

Second step - are you getting any errors in your console?

The next thing I would try is: inside your `selectAnswer` function, use `console.log()` to print out the result of `userAns == correctAns` and see if it's ever true. It's possible that it's not incrementing because it's never hitting that line, because the `userAns` and `correctAns` are never a match.

I hope this sets you on the right path but if not, post your HTML as well and I'll test it.

Comment: The first issue is cause i edited it on stackoverflow - it was a very silly question and didn't notice the appostrophe. However, i checked the second issue to see if it's even passing through the if statement and it's not. I have my entire code editted above incase you need to work on.

Comment: Haha no problem. Thanks for sharing the HTML. The problem lies in your selectAnswer function - you're passing a parameter called 'answer' but I don't think it's what you expect it to be. It doesn't have any textContent so when you're comparing that to the rightAnswer, it's always false.

Comment: thank you for your help - it was indeed an issue with comparing the two. i have solved and attached the solution above.

Comment: Glad to help @FathimaFarwin! Please accept my answer so that it shows as the solution as per the Stack Overflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers